# How to select a range that moves

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and need some help. I am setting up a file in which a user will input four rows of data and then press a command button which should be able to add only the last for rows that have been entered. how do I set it up so that the calculation will only add the most recent four rows of data?

Thanks in advance,
Shane.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Reading [Ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim x
x = Range("a1").End(xlDown).Value + Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).Value + Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(-2, 0).Value + Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(-3, 0).Value
Range("b3").Value = x
End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim x
x = Range("a1").End(xlDown).Value + Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).Value + Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(-2, 0).Value + Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(-3, 0).Value
Range("b3").Value = x
End Sub
```